# How to avoid unnecessary Firestore reads in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

*Disclaimer: I hope my description hits the nail on the head, as I put much time in this question. Please give me Feedback in the comments to improve my question so that you have enough information to give me a good answer. I build this app to support a corona vaccination center as a charity project and I don't get payed and I try to avoid spending money for firestore reads. Thus I want to reduce them.*

---

I have two web apps built with ReactJS:

1. User can generate a check-in ticket
2. Admin can check the user in.

The 1. app has firestore writes only. One write per user. I will not cover that app in more details as it would not have issues.

The 2. app has 1 write per user when he gets checked in and I have issues with the reads, as the app currentyl hits the 50.000 free reads per day very quickly. And I have 3.000 users only (blue line is read and purple line is write):

[image: Firestore reads issue]

The Admin app has three views: `CheckInView`, `UserArchive` and `UserView`. The app uses a Firestore database with one `users` collection. I build the app to just work and now I want to imrpove the code to avoid unnecessary reads to the firestore app.

For the `CheckInView` I need the `.onSnapshot()` so that the Admin doesn't need to manually refresh the page and sees new users automatically. It is only reading the users, that are not checked in (`.where("checkedin", "==", null)`).

The `UserArchive` should show **all** users that are already checked in (`.where("checkedin", "!=", null)`). It has an input field to filter/search specific users. There are round about 200-300 users per day and maximum of 10 users not cheked in at the same time. That means 200-300 new users every day. Thus, 200-300 more reads every day.

For the `UserView` I am reading again but only one user. I am not really sure why my app is scaling the reads so hard. Maybe this is happening when you go from the `UserView` back to the `UserArchive`, because it is fetching all users again and again and again.

I could switch from `.onSnapshot()` to `.get()` in the `UserArchive` but I'm not sure, if this resolved by issue. Maybe not.

Maybe there is someone more experienced than I am with firestore reads and can check my code and sees the issue with that many reads.

This is my mutch minified code with the basic functionallity:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import firebase from "./firebase";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/checkin" component={CheckInView} />
          <Route exact path="/userview/:udi" component={UserView} />
          <Route exact path="/userarchive" component={UserArchive} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

export const CheckInView = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .where("infected", "==", null)
      .onSnapshot((fetchedUsers) => {
        setUsers(fetchedUsers.docs.map((user) => user.data()));
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [setUsers]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/userarchive">- Archive</Link>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <div key={user.uid}>
          <Link to={`/userview/${user.uid}`}>{user.name}</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const UserArchive = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .where("infected", "!=", null)
      .onSnapshot((fetchedUsers) => {
        setUsers(fetchedUsers.docs.map((user) => user.data()));
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [setUsers]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/checkin">- CheckIn</Link>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={search}
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
      {users
        .filter((e) => e.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
        .map((user) => (
          <div key={user.uid}>
            <Link to={`/userview/${user.uid}`}>{user.name}</Link>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const UserView = ({ match }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(match.params.uid)
      .onSnapshot((user) => {
        setUser(user.data());
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [setUser, match.params.uid]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{user !== undefined ? user.name : "No Valid User."}</div>
      <Link to="/checkin">Back</Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

Is it a good idea, to add **one** `.onSnapshot()` to the `App` component and pass it to all views and filter it based on my requirements like:

- `users.fiter(e => e.checkedin === true)` for UserArchive
- `users.fiter(e => e.checkedin === false)` for CheckInView
- `users.fiter(e => e.uid === march.params.uid)` for UserView

Answer (score 0):

Hi the reason your read is going is, you `effect` function is run every time your component renders.

For eg

```
const UserView = ({ match }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(match.params.uid)
      .onSnapshot((user) => {
        setUser(user.data());
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>{user !== undefined ? user.name : "No Valid User."}</div>
      <Link to="/checkin">Back</Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

This component will render 1st time, the effect will run to get `user snapshot` then `setUser` => by updating your state, the component will render again => and if your component render, the effect will run again.

That why you have been credit alots on reading.

So you can do adjust by turn your effect to only run one time only

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(match.params.uid)
      .onSnapshot((user) => {
        setUser(user.data());
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

By change to above, the effect will only run when component mounted

Comment: `useEffect` hook is also dependent on `match.params.uid` so it is better to pass it in the dependency array `[match.params.uid]`

Comment: Sorry that was an issue on my side. In my real app, all the useEffects are depending on the related `setUsers` and on the `match.params.uid`. I updated my code. So with that, I still get that many reads.

Comment: if so, I think you should log on the effect function to detect how many times it was called for a full end-to-end flow. By doing so, you will detect with part call the service most