# Unexpected reads (firestore) on app load (react routes)

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, routes

I'm aware of the console consuming reads if it's open while writing to the database, this is not the issue here.

My question in particular is regarding the first time the app is loaded:
Does every component get mounted (and therefore, fetch data) eventhough we haven't clicked on any of the pages yet?

```
<App>
  <NavBar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="page1" element={<Page1 />} />      
      <Route path="page2" element={<Page2 />} />   
    </Routes>
</App>
```

`Supose Page1 and Page2 follow a similar scheme like this: useEffect with empty dependency to fetch data from firestore to show a list of something, users or whatever and set data.`

```
useEffect(() => {    
    
  async function fetchData() {
            
    try {
      const colRef = doc(db, 'COLLECTION')
      const myDocs = await getDocs(colRef)
      ... //do something to get the data from each doc   
      setData(data)        

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)        
    }
  } 
  fetchData()
}, []) //only once on mounting component
```

I get a spike in reads on firestore console usage right after "npm run dev" and I have not touched anything on the browser yet, just a plain frozen Home page.

I've tried lazy loading with no success either.

Obviously my goal is to prevent unnecessary reads. Thx.

Comment: Can you have a look at this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70910727/18265702),  [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67050715/18265702) and [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434555/18265702).

Comment: Yep. Already read all the similar posts and I've trying to figure this out for a quite a bit of time, can't find a direct answer on the internet. 

Just to give some more context: I have console.logs whenever a firebase function is happening and the console is always blank. As I said, I just fire up the run dev and don't touch anything. 

I'm guessing, somehow, it has to do with the mounting of the components on the App Routes on the first load. But again... it makes no sense to me that the console.logs are not coming up but the reads are there on the firestore console usage.. :S

Comment: To troubleshoot this, I'd `console.log(myDocs.docs.length)` right after `getDocs` and check the output. Whatever number that shows, is how many reads the code causes. If you see more reads in the usage stats, they're not coming from that specific run of this code.